# Window buttons vanish after upgrading metacity packages

Tags: 11.04, unity, metacity, window-decoration

I am using Unity. Today I upgraded some Metacity packages to the latest version with Synaptic Package Manager. After restarting the Window Buttons are gone, but the borders are still present.

I don't want to use Emerald.

Comment: You can't use compiz and metacity together. On natty, unity uses compiz and classic uses metacity. So which one are you using ? and which one is broken ?

Comment: what application did you use to take the screenshot btw?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Quite likely what happened is that you have not upgraded a related package (such as the unity-window-decorator's required libs (metacity-common, libmetacity-private).

Wait a while, then check for updates manually again (`sudo apt-get update` in a terminal, or refresh your sources in synaptic) and you should see some new package updates.
Once you apply these, run unity (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>>unity or logout and login again) to reload the window decorations.